# Non modal "status" form

Tags: c#, forms, non-modal

At the beginning of a section of C# code that could take several seconds to complete, I'd like to display a non modal form with a label that just says, "Please wait..."

```
WaitForm myWaitForm = null;

try
{
  // if conditions suggest process will take awhile
  myWaitForm = new WaitForm();
  myWaitForm.Show();

  // do stuff
}
finally
{
  if (myWaitForm != null)
  {
    myWaitForm.Hide();
    myWaitForm.Dispose();
    myWaitForm = null;
  }
}
```

The problem: the WaitForm doesn't completely display before the rest of the code ties up the thread.  So I only see the frame of the form.  In Delphi (my old stomping ground) I would call Application.ProcessMessages after the Show()  Is there an equivalent in C#?  Is there a canned "status" form that I can use in situations like this?  Is there a better way to approach this?

Thanks in advance.
David Jennings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i agree on the "other thread" suggestion, but for simple and short purposes Application.DoEvents() will do.

Answer (score 5):

Yo need to run the do stuff part in a different thread.
and then all `myWaitForm.Show()`
Take a look at `BackgroundWorker` class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: Thanks very much.  I have never looked at the BackgroundWorker.  Looks like it simplifies multithreading a great deal.  Might not be the best thing for this specific situation.  But I'll definitely use it later in the same application.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better move your "do stuff" code to other thread.
and use Application.DoEvents() to proces the form messages

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is "splash screen".

Here are a few related comments.  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=splash+screen+c%23